# Deploy Visual Studio 2015 SSAS-Tabular Model project from Tabular Editor - no data in destination database

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a Visual Studio (VS) 2015 project for SSAS-Tabular Model, a simple project with a couple of tables.

I am using **Tabular Editor (TE)** tool (2.17.0) for the first time for deployment.

This VS project is to be deployed to a new database that does not yet exist in the SSAS-Tabular Model server.

The deployment from TE is successful; however the destination database in the SSAS-Tabular Model server does not have data; it has only the data model, i.e. the empty tables of the VS project.

How to import the data ?

Where am I wrong ? I can post some screenshots if needed.

Can someone provide suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying a model to a server is a metadata-only operation.  After deployment you must [Process the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/process-database-table-or-partition-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) to load data.  In Power BI this is called "Refresh" but it's the same thing.

Visual Studio processes the database after deployment by default.  Tabular Editor does not.

Note that Tabular Editor 3 [supports refreshing models](https://docs.tabulareditor.com/onboarding/refresh-preview-query.html).

Comment: Is there a 'Process' option in Tabular Editor ?

Comment: I don't think so; use SSMS for that.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of deployment from Tabular Editor ?

Comment: Tabular Editor is considered to be an 'easy-to-use' Visual Studio, if I am right.

Comment: Yes, but it's for designing tabular models.  SSMS is still the main tool for administration and operations.

Comment: I am really surprised!! I thought Tabular Editor could conveniently substitute Visual Studio

Comment: @user3812887 it's a free, open-source tool. You can't expect a single developer writing some code in his spare time to compete with a full team at Microsoft. If you want more features, consider purchasing Tabular Editor 3.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to with PowerPoint?  If not, please consider removing that tag.